# how to make ajax synchronous?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How do I make function out of this?

```
         //check if station is alive
         $.ajax({
           url: "lib/grab.php",
           data: "check_live=1&stream_url="+valueSelected,
           type: "GET",
               success: function (resp) {
                 if (resp == 1) {
                   play_this(valueSelected);
                 } else {
                   //
                 }
               },
               error: function (e) {
                 console.dir(e);
               }
         });
```

I thought I could do something like this:

```
function is_alive(valueSelected) {
result = false;
             //check if station is alive
             $.ajax({
               url: "lib/grab.php",
               data: "check_live=1&stream_url="+valueSelected,
               type: "GET",
                   success: function (resp) {
                     if (resp == 1) {
                       result = true;
                     } else {
                       //
                     }
                   },
                   error: function (e) {
                     console.dir(e);
                   }
             });
return result;
}
```

But obviously due to asynchronous nature of ajax call, result always returns false.

What is the trick of dealing with this situation?

Seems to work:

```
        //check if station is alive
        function is_alive(url) {
          //
          var result = false;
          //
          return $.ajax({
            url: "lib/grab.php",
            data: "check_live=1&stream_url="+url,
            type: "GET",
                success: function (resp) {
                  if (resp == 1) {
                    //
                    result = true;
                    //
                  }
                },
                error: function (e) {
                  console.dir(e);
                }
          }).then(function() {
            return $.Deferred(function(def) {
              def.resolveWith({},[result,url]);
            }).promise();
          });
        }
```

And call it like this:

```
    //Change song on select, works both for fav and station lists
    $(document).on("click", ".ui-listview li a", function(){
      var valueSelected = $(this).data("station-url");
      //
      is_alive(valueSelected).done(function(result,url){
          if (result) {
            //
            play_this(valueSelected);
            //
          }
      });
    });
```

Comment: set `async: false` in your ajax call

Comment: You shouldn't make it synchronous if it all possible. Synchronous AJAX calls block anything else going on in the browser. Ideally you should consider returning a promise from your function and then have whatever calls that function act on the returned promise.

Comment: @MichaelMior can you extrapolate on promise? i like that way better than making ajax call sync.

Comment: it will freeze your browser

Comment: @showdev Solutions here are better though!

Comment: @ArunKillu The simplest way to go about this is to simply return the result of `$.ajax(...).promise()` from your function. Then when you call the function you would call it like `is_alive(foo).then(function(data) { ... })`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't have to make it synchronous to make it a useful function.

```
function is_alive(valueSelected) {
    //check if station is alive
    return $.ajax({
        url: "lib/grab.php",
        data: "check_live=1&stream_url=" + valueSelected,
        type: "GET",
        error: function (e) {
            console.dir(e);
        }
    });
}

is_alive(somevalue).then(function(result){
    console.log(result, somevalue);
});
```

Comment: First time I hear about promise(). Gonna read about that. And thanks!

Comment: p.s. I couldn't make it work as you wrote it. So I updated my post to include answer. What do you think? I was receiving error about resp not being defined. When I defined it outside ajax it was always returning false.

Comment: I feel I shouldn't upvote this, because it doesn't actually answer the original question.  On the other hand, this is exactly the answer I believe *should* be given, so... have some rep. :p

Comment: @cloudfeet actually this is exactly what I wanted to know, I simply couldn't come up with a better title.

Comment: @KevinB if I don't define it inside function outside ajax, than I get js error in console: resp not defined.

Comment: @KevinB I updated my post to show exactly what I'm doing now, and it works. But if I replace this def.resolveWith({},[result,url]); with def.resolveWith({},[resp,url]); I get undefined variable problem.

Comment: @KevinB this is live: http://mac.idev.ge:800/radio/

Comment: If I copy your code directly, I get Uncaught ReferenceError: resp is not defined error. Please take a look at live site, it has your code line to line. http://mac.idev.ge:800/radio/

Comment: @KevinB sure, here it is: http://pastebin.com/CbMptKit, this errors out. I could make jsfiddle but my ajax doesn't work there.

Answer (score 9):

You can supply the async: false option

```
function is_alive(valueSelected) {
     result = false;
             //check if station is alive
             $.ajax({
               async: false,
               url: "lib/grab.php",
               data: "check_live=1&stream_url="+valueSelected,
               type: "GET",
                   success: function (resp) {
                     if (resp == 1) {
                       result = true;
                     } else {
                       //
                     }
                   },
                   error: function (e) {
                     console.dir(e);
                   }
             });
return result;
}
```

Comment: I upvote cause you actually answered directly my question. But other answers seem like a better way to go.

Comment: Thanks ! Yes, I believe promises are the better way to go. Blocking the main thread is probably a "bad thing"

Comment: After an hour of googling, this is the only answer that has worked for me. Thankyou.